# Starting point for a SQL Server query to call .NET method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a starting point on techonlogies (what to use, what to search for) to accomplish my needs.

On one side, I have a .NET web service that send out SMS to our employee. It's my alerting service. The service itself takes some parameters for input and then it sends a JSON request to a major mobile service provider that then delivers the text message to the suscriber using our short code.

On the other side I have my desktop software for operations, it uses the web services to send SMS for what ever business logic I have programmed. This software connects to a Microsoft SQL server database (2012). This is where I would like to work, at the database level.

I'm loking to a way to call my web service methods from a SQL Query to later implement something that will run with the SQL Agent or with some triggers (preffered method). Or a way to directly send JSON request directly from SQL Server.

I've heard of SQL CRL but it seems to be a huge topic and before starting to learn it I juste want to make sure it's the right thing I need or if i'm on the wrong path.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Edit: 
This is the .NET code that I would like to call from a SQL query/sp/function/trigger

```
var smsService = new SMSWebMethod.ServiceClient();

var smsRequest = new Dictionary<string, string>();
smsRequest["user"] = "our username with the provider";
smsRequest["pass"] = "our password with the provider";
smsRequest["address"] = "The suscriber";
smsRequest["requestId"] = new Guid().ToString();
smsRequest["message"] = "The actual SMS message";
smsRequest["sender"] = "our short code";
smsRequest["modifiedByID"] = CurrentUser.Employee.ID.ToString();
smsRequest["MemberContactID"] = theMemberContactID.ToString();
smsRequest["AppointmentID"] = new Guid().ToString();
smsRequest["UserID"] = theUserID.ToString();
smsRequest["IsQuestion"] = requireAnswer.ToString();

smsService.SendSMS(smsRequest);
```

Comment: If you really need to call webservices directly from sql I would recommend CLR. Before getting there though I would question if you really need to call webservices from sql. Shouldn't that be done in your application?

Comment: The database is the wrong place to be sending text messages. You *could* code something in a .Net stored proc but I really wouldn't go there. This sounds like the sort of job for a Windows service.

Comment: What is "right" depends on quite a bit more information than is presented here. But, it is not necessarily wrong, as some are inclined to say. If you want to learn more about SQLCLR in general, I have been writing a series on it: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/). Calling a WebService can be done via `HttpWebRequest` if not also more direct WebService methods. But, if you  want to do it without any coding, the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote) has a function `INET_GetWebPages` that does this; but it is not in the Free version.

Comment: @Sean Lange The desktop application isn't always running, specially during the night but some tasks may expire during the night and require an sms to be send without user intervention.

Comment: Well there must be some kind of application running. Otherwise there would be no new data that would cause the need to send a text message.

Comment: The reason I would like to go with CLR is to build a trigger that says: "Each time there's a new line in database.dbo.alerts, call smsservice.SendSMS(smsrequest)

Comment: Just to have it clearly stated: while I see no issues with calling a web service from the DB, I would not place such a call inside of a trigger given that triggers act within the scope of a transaction surrounding the DML statement that fired the trigger. I know one person who called `COMMIT` first and then did the Web Service call to ensure that the locks were released in case the call took longer than expected or errored, but I would still suggest doing a simple insert into a queue table that a SQL Agent job reads from to send the messages.

Comment: @Sean Lange Yes there is something running, it's a website where customers can register their need (we manage employee work schedule for hospitals) but I do not own the code of this website (asp.net) and the business logic is already all inside my webservice which I own the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it, right now your architecture looks like this:

```
SMS Service       DB
      \          /
       \        /
         Desktop
```

You'd like it to look more like this:

```
SMS Service  <---- DB
      \           /
       \         /
         Desktop
```

That sounds like a bit of a mess: everything talking to everything else. That way lies madness. If anything, you may be ready for an application server:

```
 SMS Service       DB
      \           /
       \         /
         App Server
             |
             |
          Desktop
```

Where the App Server is the starting point for a service layer in a service-oriented architecture. Note that with this architecture, the Desktop client never talks directly to the database any more.

Also remember that I said "IF". I really think the thing to do is process this at the desktop level. If these messages are the result of agent jobs, it may be time to think about how those agent jobs are scheduled, such that they're called from an scheduler application that can handle logging and alerts.

Comment: That seems like an ideal idea, but it's out of my knowledge to build this. I'll like to stay within what I currently have in place.